# How do I translate the "On behalf of Label"?

Tags: civicontribute, translation

Using a multilingual install, on the configuration page of a contribution page, the "On behalf of Label" doesn't provide a multilingual option.

Switching languages and inputting the translation into this box just overwrites the previous one.

Similar issue with the "Honoree Section Title".

Using Drupal 7 + CiviCRM 5.28.4

Answer (score 1):

This is a civicrm core bug, fixed in 5.30, as per Demerit's comment below.

These labels live in the table civicrm_uf_join as the 'module_data' field.

Comment: I thought honoree was fixed in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16838, or maybe I'm reading this issue wrong and it's slightly different?

Comment: Ah very good - that was merged after 5.28.4